# Rails has_one relation eager_load with polymorphic through polymorphic (or around)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, eager-loading, has-one

I would like to achieve the following:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :number, as: numberable, through: typeable #<- This relation is the thing I want to have but doesn't work like this (and many other ways I tried)
    belongs_to :typeable, polymorphic: true
end

# Example Document Type
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :number, as: :numberable
    has_one :document, as: :typeable
end

# Number
class DocumentTypeNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :numberable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Since typeable and numberable are going to contain the equal record I could do a *left join on numberable.id = typeable.id and numberable.type = typeable.type*. However I can't get this working using a rails has_one relation (I guess I try to abuse it to hard).. So my question, what would be the best way to achieve the following with the data model above:

```
Document.eager_load(:number)
Document.find(1).number
# Or:
Document.eager_load(typeable: { :number })
Document.find(1).typeable.number
```

And here in a graphical way..
[image: Model]